# How to use built-in membership in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, ef-database-first

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, then i created a new project with authentication of individual users account.
I want to use built-in membership (account and manage controller) and manage them in sql server management studio, because i will use (Database First approach)
currently i will use them in local server, i will migrate them later to another server.

the most important thing for me right know is managing the database tables from SQL server management studio>

Current Connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Niqaaty-20170912110206.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Niqaaty-20170912110206;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: my problem is that i have built-in models like (account and manage) how i can connect them to my sql server. i want to see my models as tables in sql server management studio.i don't know where is the location of my db

Comment: Please go through some basic tutorial regarding asp.net built-in membership. It is all explained many times there.

Answer (score 0):

just config membership related stuff as same as when you use webform, like db, provide, even login and logout page

then add [Authorize] attribute to your controllers or actions which need to be protected by membership, done

Comment: I knew this point, my problem is that i have built-in models like (account and manage) how i can connect them to my sql server. i want to see my models as tables in sql server management studio.i don't know where is the location of my db.